# Mapping NCLOB in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I've two column in Oracle table:

- firstColumn nvarchar2
- secondColumn nclob

Mapping in the class:

```
@Column(length = 1000, columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (1000)")
@Nationalized
private String firstColumn;

@Lob
@Nationalized
private String secondColumn;
```

Additionaly property hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data is set on true.

Update firstColumn works correctly for chinese characters, but secondColumn in DB contains something like inverted question marks.

I tried with many combination set of annotation:

```
@Lob
@Nationalized
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.NClobType")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedNClobType")
```

but without success.

- DB: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition
- Driver: ojdbc7
- Hibernate: 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem with mapping. The solution (workaround?) is:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "nclob", length=100000) 
@Nationalized 
private String secondColumn;
```